# Footer display bug responsive design

Tags: css, media-queries

on the following site for responsive design for smartphones, a display bug has occurred for the footer block for pages:

[page1](http://www.arsilver.fr/photos-studio/)

[page2](http://www.arsilver.fr/photos-identites/)

How could i fix it please

here is the display bug images :

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJaEy.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ityu.png)

Comment: "a display bug has occurred for the footer block for pages:" What bug?

Comment: i have updated post , the bug is for the display in responsive design as shown in images

Comment: well at first sight it seams to be a problem with floats and or position: relative|absolute because it looks like some elements are taking out of the normal page flow and starting to overflap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cut below div:

```
<div class="sous_content container"><!--Your contents--></div>
```

And paste it outside the this div:

```
<div class="image_slider">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'margin-top' for the footer element, only for mobile version. it would solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think "margin-top" is a real solution for the need. The aspect will be good but it's not the best way to do it. The problem is on his site construction. He has to be 3 categories : header, site, footer. There it seems that the footer isn't considered as a block.

Comment: I agreed with the site construction issue, just give the simplest solution that someone can comes up with the original problem since it seems not harming